# Import Xen Server VM to Hyper V (Windows 2012 R 2 Std. edition)

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, xen

I have Xen Server having version 7.0 and few VM's (having windows OS) are there.

Now I have exported particular VM in ".xva" format and ".ova" format. As I want to integrate this with hypervisor of "Windows Server 2012 R 2 Std. edition" so how to do that ?

-As per search direct integration was not possible as mentioned on [this official forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4c0ff045-58ca-427f-b8c9-45283a3d8534/ova-and-hyper-v?forum=winserverhyperv)

-Hence trying to convert it into other virtual formats such as (.vmdk) but not able to find any convertor which converts to .vmdk

-Also Xen can not export directly to .vmdk format.

-At the end in short I want to import my VM  with hypervisor of "Windows Server 2012 R 2 Std. edition" so how to do that ? any alternative/any 3rd party tool available ??